# Child class calling superclass constructor

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm trying to establish a class inheriting from another one. In this case, I have a superclass DataScraper that is supposed to have two children, JSONDataScraper and XMLDataScraper. Well... it doesn't work. When I compile, I get the following message :

> 'identifier' : constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions (C2250)

datascraper.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Qstring>

class DataScraper
{
private:
    std::vector<QString> GetFiles(const QString folder);

protected:
    std::vector<QString> filesToAnalyze;

public:
    DataScraper(const QString folderPath);
    DataScraper(const std::vector<QString>& paths);

};
```

datascraper.cpp

```
#include "datascraper.h"
#include "Windows.h"

DataScraper::DataScraper(const std::vector<QString>& paths)
{
    //...
}

DataScraper::DataScraper(const QString folderPath)
{
    //...
}

std::vector<QString> DataScraper::GetFiles(const QString folder)
{
    //...
}
```

And now, JSONDataScraper files.

```
#include "rapidjson.h"
#include "datascraper.h"
#include "streamreader.h"
#include <QString>

class JSONDataScraper : public DataScraper
{
private:
    StreamReader *FileContentsReader;

public:
    JSONDataScraper(QString folderPath);
    JSONDataScraper(std::vector<QString> files);
};
```

jsondatascraper.cpp

```
#include "jsondatascraper.h"
#include "streamreader.h"
#include "datascraper.h"
#include <QString>

JSONDataScraper::JSONDataScraper(const std::vector<QString>& paths) : DataScraper(paths)
{
    //...
}

JSONDataScraper::JSONDataScraper(const QString& pathToFile) : DataScraper(pathToFile)
{
    //...
}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: First step - construct a [MCVE].

Comment: Re: "superclass" and "children": use consistent terminology. "Super-class" goes with "sub-class", while "child" goes with "parent". But if you **really** want consistency, go with the terms used in the language definition: "base class" and "derived class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructors for `JSONDataScraper` have differing parameter lists in the declaration and definition respectively. You should have another error message about this.

Your definition is thus not recognised as a declared constructor, so the *ctor-initialiser* is not valid there.

```
JSONDataScraper(std::vector<QString> files);
JSONDataScraper::JSONDataScraper(const std::vector<QString>& paths) : DataScraper(paths)
//                               ^^^^^^                    ^
{
   //...
}

JSONDataScraper(QString folderPath);
JSONDataScraper::JSONDataScraper(const QString& pathToFile) : DataScraper(pathToFile)
//                               ^^^^^^       ^
{
    //...
}
```

You're basically confusing the heck out of your compiler.

**Fix the parameter lists to match and everything should be fine.**